# Is there a way to change the spacing of Android buttons on cordova-plugin-dialogs?

Tags: android, cordova, button, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I developed a hybrid mobile app.
I was wondering myself if there is a way to change the space between buttons raised from [cordova-plugin-dialogs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/blob/master/src/android/Notification.java) on Android.

They usually look like:

[image]

I'm not very familiar with native development (on  Android), so is there anything I can change to affect the spacing of those buttons? e.g. on Android manifest or something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution here falls in the "[Create your custom dialog in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)" solution, actually. Those are the default dialogs, and the buttons are generated automatically. I don't think you can control anything else than the theme, texts and pretty much that's it.

If you want to be able to completely modify it, [create a custom native dialog](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) (for each platform you're targeting, if possible in iOS -not sure right now), and create a cordova plugin that opens that dialog, and returns something when the buttons are clicked...

Or simply create a "dialog" (**modal**) in html. That will be much simpler, if you're already using cordova.